# How to pass dynamic param in angular $resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngresource

I want to pass dynamic value of default param in $resource. Please look into the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kEXCRMna7xOcrEiBVf9Z?p=preview). Here when I had passed default param in factory as

```
app.factory('myFactory', ["$resource", function($resource) {
    return $resource('http://google.com', {timeStamp : (new Date()).getTime()}, {
        query : {
            method : 'GET',
            isArray : true,
            cache : false
        }
    })
}]);
```

I want default param timeStamp to be dynamic.
currently when i click on **Refresh** Button the param value goes always same **(Check in console)**

> I need this functionality because IE make cache on **GET** method and I don't want cache data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you.

```
app.factory('myFactory', ["$resource", function($resource) {
    return $resource('http://google.com', {}, {
        query : {
            method : 'GET',
            isArray : true,
            params : { ts : Date.now } // <-- new timestamp will be genrated and assigned to ts
        }
    })
}]);
```

each time you invoke `myFactory.query()` method a querystring `ts` with current timestamp value will appear in url.

Comment: it still does not give the dynamic values of **ts**. once the value of **ts** is set then if you click button multiple times same value goes.

Comment: Oh yes, I made mistake there by calling Date.now() directly. You can try this edited one.

Comment: Why does the edited version work? And could @AmitMourya just update the default param to { timestamp: Date.now }

Answer (score 0):

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngResource']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,myFactory) {
  $scope.refresh = function(){
    myFactory.query({timeStamp : (new Date()).getTime()}).$promise.then(function(){})
  }
});
app.factory('myFactory', ["$resource", function($resource) {
    return $resource('http://google.com', {}, {
        query : {
            method : 'GET',
            isArray : true,
            cache : false
        }
    })
}]);
```

Code inside of a function is not executed until the function is called. However within a declaration of an object, all of it is executed as the object's being created. You may as well have of had this.

```
app.factory('myFactory', ["$resource", function($resource) {
    return $resource('http://google.com', {timestamp: 1433865286924}, {
        query : {
            method : 'GET',
            isArray : true,
            cache : false
        }
    })
}]);
```

Comment: Hi @Matt I dont want to pass the parameter while calling the factory function. I want it to be done with default params

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer as said by Lekhnath is

```
app.factory('myFactory', ["$resource", function($resource) {
    return $resource('http://google.com', {}, {
        query : {
            method : 'GET',
            isArray : true,
            params : { ts : Date.now } // <-- new timestamp will be genrated and assigned to ts
        }
    })
}]);
```

or if we want to pass in default param section it can be done as

```
app.factory('myFactory', ["$resource", function($resource) {
    return $resource('http://google.com', { ts : Date.now }, { // <-- new timestamp will be genrated and assigned to ts
        query : {
            method : 'GET',
            isArray : true
        }
    })
}]);
```